Pointcloud created by rgbd has wrong orentation in rviz (sim in ignition gazebo)
hi im trying rtab mapping in gazebo sim (ignition gazebo) i changed the orientation to rpy="-90 0 -90" and added <gz_frame_id>camera_link_optical</gz_frame_id> to my rgbd plugin but the orientation is at the bottom and it works well for other angles

you need to apply an external transform when creating point cloud from depth image. I'm using open3d for the same and I had to transform the point cloud with this matrix Tc = np.array([[1,  0,  0,  0],
[0,  -1,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  -1,  0],
[0,  0,  0,  1]]).reshape(4,4)
hope this helps

hi can you help me with one example?
